# I'm looking to convert my MS-DOS .bat file into the equivalent linux .sh file

Tags: linux, windows, shell, batch-file

Basically I have to make my linux program do the same thing as my MS-DOS. Could someone help with pointers and things like that?
All the program currently does, is pull a menu for basic, advanced account creation and close.
Advanced has nothing in atm, and close does what you expect. Basic then asks you for:
Full name
Username
Password
It then saves it all in a .log file (after checking for usernames already entered) along with the exact time of creation. For example:
Badja
John Doe
123
23/04/2015 15:07:32.61

```
@echo off
c:
:1
set curdir=%test%
echo Welcome to OP-SYS Account creation. Please choose which mode you would like to  continue in.
echo.
echo [1] Basic Account Creation
echo [2] Advanced Account Creation
echo [3] Exit
echo.

REM Menu choices
set /p cat=
if %cat%==1 (
goto 2
) else if %cat%==2 (
goto 3
) else if %cat%==3 (
goto 5
) else (
goto 4
)
:2
REM Basic account creation
echo Welcome to basic account creation.
REM user enters details

REM Username
echo Please Enter a Username
set /p username=
echo.
REM Real Name
echo Please enter your full name
set /p fullname=
echo.
REM Password
echo Please enter a password
set /p password=
echo.
REM Real name

REM Save to file
if exist %username%.log (
echo User name already exists, please enter a new user name to create an account, or return to the log in screen

goto 1
) else (
echo %username% >> %username%.log
echo %fullname% >> %username%.log
echo %password% >> %username%.log
echo %date% %time% >> %username%.log )
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > NUL
REM pause
goto end

:3
REM Advanced account creation
echo Welcome to advanced account creation.
echo This is not complete, please return to main menu.
Pause
goto 1

:4
REM Error
echo error
echo.
goto 1


:5
REM Exit
echo Goodbye.

goto end

:end
exit​
```

I know there are a few things that can't be copied over to linux, but I just don't know where to start, this is my basis:

```
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("cat 1" "cat 2" "end")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "cat 1")
            echo "Basic"
            ;;
        "cat 2")
            echo "Advanced"
            ;;
        "end")
            break
            ;;
            *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

Any help would be amazing guys!

Comment: Describe what the original script does in prose for those of us who can't (easily) read batch scripts please.

Comment: I have done this, and edited some formatting :)

Comment: Is that shell snippet not working? What exactly are you stuck on at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function choice1 {

echo "Do stuff here to create an account"

}

function choice2 {

echo "Get the point?"

}

function choice3 {

exit

}

#### Main

echo "Welcome to OP-SYS Account creation. Please choose which mode you would like to continue in."
echo

echo "[1] Basic Account Creation
[2] Advanced Account Creation
[3] Exit"
echo

read CHOICE #### This loads your choice into a variable

eval choice"$CHOICE" ### This is evaluation awesomeness
```

Comment: This is very clean and straight-forward.  You create functions with you choice numbers as part of the names, assign them first, and then use the eval (short for evaluate) command to run the function, so typing 1 would call the function named "choice1", etc.

Comment: make sure that your script is executable with: chmod 700 SCRIPTNAME

Comment: Thanks for all the help; I'm now confused down the line on making errors, can you help? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084495/shell-file-to-create-user-input-errors-equilivant-of-msdos[/link]

Comment: Yes, up arrow my answer and post what you have, please.

Comment: I've linked what I have, also.  Until I have 15 rep, I can't upvote. I hate being new here.

Answer (score 0):

If the eval seems strange, you can go with a more traditional case...esac statement to call the various functions.  I would suggest getting your menu cycling and escaping the way that you want before adding in your special function.

```
clear
 echo "Welcome to OP-SYS Account creation. Please choose which mode you would like to continue in."
 echo

echo "[1] Basic Account Creation
[2] Advanced Account Creation
[3] Exit"
echo
```